# Converting multiple docx files asynchronously to pdf using headless libreoffice in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, libreoffice

I have put together the following code below to convert some docx files to pdf. Since it is a heavy operation I figured I would do this asynchronously since they document isnt used right away for anything else and is for visual purposes only on my front end which I account for loading in javascript.

My code is as follows:

```cs
public static void ConvertToPDF(string PathToItemToConvert, string PathToLibrePortable)
{

        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PathToItemToConvert);
            string fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(PathToItemToConvert);

            var pdfProcess = new Process();
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.FileName = PathToLibrePortable;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.Arguments =
                String.Format("--norestore --nofirststartwizard --headless --convert-to pdf  \"{0}\""
                                        , fileName);
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = fileDir;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            pdfProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            pdfProcess.Start();

            string output = pdfProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
        }
}
```

I use it in the following fashion in an API as follows:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> ConvertDocs()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        MyTools.ConvertToPDF(SomeFilePath, locationOfLibreOfficeSoffice);
    });
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        MyTools.ConvertToPDF(AnotherFilePath, locationOfLibreOfficeSoffice);
    });
}
```

This does not draw any errors but the second pdf is never created. If I comment out the other pdf code the second one will create. Its almost as if libreoffice cannot convert two pdfs at once despite I am starting separate threads with `Task.Run()`. Is there a way to do this or am I messing up something?

Comment: What is the purpose of `bool converted`? It isn't used anywhere... Similarly, you aren't saving `string output` anywhere - and this code likely wont' work anyway as the stdout will contain binary data, but `string` values cannot represent binary data...

Comment: Code updated based on those comments.

Comment: Some other things happen in that task.run() for each so I removed ConvertToPDF from being asynchronous and conetinue with the two Task.Run()

Comment: I will handle logging at a later point in my project but thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Okay so making the changes Dai mentioned fixes my error. The nested Task.Run() that was occuring must have caused some sort of bug. However, this is now very slow so I feel as though its running synchronously instead. I was using Task.Run() so they would just convert in the background and wouldnt hold up ConvertDocs Task. Am I doing something wrong because everything I read only says to use await with Task.Run() but I feel like that is why this is being held up.

Comment: _"everything I read only says to use `await` with `Task.Run()`"_ - That's not a well-informed position, may I ask where you're seeing people say that? Also, "`async`" does not mean "run in the background" - to do that use `QueueUserWorkItem` or `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: @Dai I have always believe async with await will not complete the async function if there is currently an await present as it is waiting for that to complete the promise? Is running in the background using the methods you propose make more sense than task.run() without await or are they similar in a sense?

Comment: Any log or error for why the ones did not complete? Did you use my code above with libreoffice or the unoconv??

Comment: @Dai So do you have any solution for converting this to  async to allow multiple pdfs  to be converted simultaneously'?